# How to add vala language into some existing c/c++ project?

Tags: c++, cmake, vala, meson-build

`Vala` has c# like syntax and compiles to c code for performance, I would like to try it with some of my existing projects.

But my existing projects are all c/c++ (mainly `c++` with `cmake` build system) project, how to add vala gradually, for example, only for newly defined classes into my existing project?

**Background:**
Some of my projects have both `.cpp` and `.proto` files: `.proto` files are compiled to `.cc` file by `protoc`, then the rest of my project can use it without any problem as long as I configured the cmake build file.
I think it's a similar case for a project with c++ and vala: vala is compiled into .c file and then used by other c++ code.

I think it's possible, but I don't know how. Any ideas or examples?

I heard `meson` is popular in vala world, should meson configuration be involved?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd be very reluctant to add a new language to an existing project – even if it generates C source-code as its output.